# Require_once doesn't seem to affect all functions?

Tags: php, scope, mysqli, require-once

Everything was working fine in my little project, until I decided to clean up a little bit and moved database-related php-files to their own folder. Then things went strange.

I am trying to use two functions here:

```
function getEntries () {
    require_once("mysqliVariables.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUname, $dbPwd, $dbName);           
    $sql = "statement...";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);

    echo $dbHost; // prints host
    return $result;
}

function getBiggestMonth () {
    require_once("mysqliVariables.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUname, $dbPwd, $dbName);           
    echo $dbHost; // prints nothing! why?       

    $sql = "statement...";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error); // this line does not run, of course.

    return $result;
}
```

I use another function in a different file (and folder) to call these functions, that starts like this:

```
function listTasks() {      
    require_once("db/mysqliFunctions.php");

    // Get entries using mysqli.
    $tasks = getEntries();

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($tasks);
    echo "</pre>"; // program works fine this far.

    $bm = getBiggestMonth(); // program breaks somehow during this function call.
```

My variables are in a php-file like so:

```
<?php   
$dbHost = "host";
$dbUname = "username";
$dbPwd = "password";
$dbName = "databasename";
```

?>

If I switch the funtion's call order, then getBiggestMonth() runs fine and the other one won't. Also, all of this **worked** fine when all the files were located in the same folder (the functions were then static functions inside a class, but that shouldn't be an issue, the same problem persists here), so I dont understand how possible variable scope can be different here, and require_once should take care of other things. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using [`require_once`](http://php.net/require_once). It will only include the configuration once. You can change it to use [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) so that it will work as you expect.

> The require_once() statement is identical to require() except PHP will
>   check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include
>   (require) it again.

You are using `require_once` to pull in a file into the scope of the `getEntries()` function. PHP keeps a record of the files that have been `require`d in so when you then call `require_once` in `getBiggestMonth()` it knows it has already been included in `getEntries()`. Because it has already been included it does not require the file in again so you don't get your variables in your `getBiggestMonth()` scope.

`require_once` does not have anything to do with variables it just monitors the files that have been included into the current PHP process.

Comment: But since it has been required already, there shouldn't be need to require it again? I don't quite follow how $dbHost isn't echoed in getBiggestMonth(), since if variables aren't already there, they will be required, and if they are, it does nothing. So it should always echo?

Comment: I have tried to explain it further in my updated answer above.

Comment: Aha! I understand now. That was way more understandable than how they put it in php.net/manual. And indeed it seems to work now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The echo statement after the return in getEntries() wont obviously work as the function exits after the return.